# How write this example in python style?

Tags: python

I've just learning python after PHP, and it's python style is very strange for me.
I'm asking for advice, how you write this code on python:

```
data = []
for line in file:
  name, surname, phone, address, email, etc = line.split(";", 6)
  data.append( {'nick': nick, 'surname': surname, 'phone': phone, 'address': address, 'email':  email, 'etc': etc} )
```

My code looks like PHP -_-

Comment: It would be finer with [proper 4-space indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ok.  Sure, you may do something like:

```
data.append(dict(zip(('name', 'surname', 'phone', 'address', 'email', 'etc'),
                     line.split(";", 6))))
```

but your variant is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks like php because you're reinventing the wheel. Don't!

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['name', 'surname', 'phone', 'address', 'email']

with open('something', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames, delimiter=';'))
```

Comment: Presuming that the file is all like that. Admittedly, it seems likely, and if so, this is the better answer.

Comment: If using Python 2, the filemode for csv files should be 'rb' (although binary mode is more important when writing csv files).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a function to do the parsing and then use `map()` to call it on each line:

```
def _parse_user_line(line):
    name, surname, phone, address, email, etc = line.split(';', 6)
    return {'nick': nick, 'surname': surname, 'phone': phone, 
            'address': address, 'email':  email, 'etc': etc}

data = map(_parse_user_line, file)
```

It might also be a good idea to assign the returned list to a single variable and then just use `fields[0]`, `fields[1]` etc. - they will be next to the dict key anyway so everyone knows what they are:

```
def _parse_user_line(line):
    u = line.split(';', 6)
    return {'nick': u[0], 'surname': u[1], 'phone': u[2], 
            'address': u[3], 'email': u[4], 'etc': u[5]}

data = map(_parse_user_line, file)
```

Now we can make this even nicer by incorporating the idea from [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216708/298479):

```
labels = 'nick surname phone address email etc'.split()
def _parse_user_line(line):
    values = line.split(';', 6)
    return dict(zip(labels, values))
data = map(_parse_user_line, file)
```

---

Never forget (a line from) [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (aka `import this`): **Readability counts.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension here:

```
[{'nick': nick, 'surname': surname, 'phone': phone, 'address': address, 'email':  email, 'etc': etc} for name, surname, phone, address, email, etc in (line.split(";", 6) for line in file)]
```

However, this is pretty hard to read due to it's length.

To construct your data, you could use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a function that produces a dict (as in [ThiefMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216703/722121)).

An alternate solution here is to create a class to hold your data:

```
def Person:
   def __init__(self, nick, surname, phone, address, email, etc):
       self.nick = nick
       self.surname = surname
       ...
```

And then construct your list using the splat operator to unpack your values:

```
data = [Person(*line.split(";", 6)) for line in file]
```

This is suitable where you intend to do more work with the data - the rule of thumb here is that if you don't make any methods to work on the data, a class is more power than you need. If you do, it might be worthwhile.